# How to delete a line every 3 lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to delete a line every 3 lines in a text file using python.
The text file I'm using follow this pattern :

```
First line is the Name of the sender

Second is the Message sent 

Third one is the Date the message was sent(ex : 8 nov. 2019 à 14:29)
```

Here is a few lines of the files for a better understanding :

```
Ad
Yes
8 nov. 2019 à 14:29
La
I don't think so
8 nov. 2019 à 13:39
Ad
Why ?
8 nov. 2019 à 13:19
La
Come on
8 nov. 2019 à 13:15
```

I already have cleaned the file for it to follow this pattern so now I'm trying to delete every lines with the date.

First I was thinking to delete every lines starting with a number but some messages starts with number so this is not the right path.
Deleting lines that are a multiple of 3 wouldn't work neither in that case.

Do you have some ideas on to how to read the file and write another one without the date lines ?

Thanks

**Edit : Thanks all, I have some great answer and there really is a multitude of way to resolve a problem in programmation. Thanks for your time !**

Comment: Read the file line by line. Check with "date" in line, then delete.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  "Do you have some ideas" is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: We expect to see code with a *specific* coding problem.  This is not a forum for thinking through your design.

Comment: Duplicate question. Here's a much more concise answer than the below ones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079875/628318
<br/>In general do try to boil your question down to it's most basic form (your title is perfect) as that helps us detect a duplicate and get you an answer quicker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This function will eliminate all lines containing target, and write to a new file:

```
import re

def file_read_and_write_B(FILE1, FILE2):
   """copies file1 to file2 excluding lines that match a regex"""
   #Use Nathan McCoy answer above with more complex regex:
   regex = re.compile(r"^[0-9]+ [a-z]+\. [0-9]+")
   with open(FILE, 'r') as fdin:
       with open(FILE2, 'w') as fdout:
           for line in fdin:
               line = line.strip()   #remove trailing/leading whitespace
               if not regex.search(line):   #skips lines that match
                   print(line, file=fdout)
```

This regex could be improved, but it will match lines that begin with "12 jun. 2019" (but also lines that begin with "1234 a. 1").

Edit: This approach doesn't consume much memory because you are only ever reading a line at a time. Compare to an alternative function:

```
def read_store_process_write(FILE1, FILE2):
    with open(FILE1, 'r') as fdin:
        temp = fdin.readlines()        #stores all lines in a file to a list
    regex = re.compile(r"^[0-9]+ [a-z]+\. [0-9]+")
    result = [x for x in temp if not regex.search(x)]  #new list w/o matches
    with open(FILE2, 'w') as fdout:
        fdout.writelines(result)
```

The problem with this approach is that if you have a gigantic file to process, you'll run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it does the same but differently. I am not very used to creating and writing in text files, so am I supposed to add a line under the print to write everything in a file ? Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: It should just work as is; this is taking a line from the input file, checking for a match, and writing that line to the output file. If you want to read everything in a file all at once then readlines/writelines is what you want (but this can clog up memory).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's say I have a list of lines like your input:

```
>>> lines
['Name (2 participants)', 'Message', 'Date (ex : 8 nov. 2019 à 14:29)']
```

Cant you just do something like the following?

```
>>> regex = re.compile("Date \(")
>>> [line for line in lines if not regex.match(line)]
['Name (2 participants)', 'Message']
```

This works because `re.match` only matches from the beginning of the line.

Any line that starts with `Date (` is skipped

Comment: Unfortunately the line with the date doesn't start with date, it start with something like in my exemple :

8 nov. 2019 à 14:29

Here is a few lines of the files for a better understanding :

Ad
Yes
8 nov. 2019 à 14:29
La
I don't think so
8 nov. 2019 à 13:39
Ad
Why ?
8 nov. 2019 à 13:19
La
Come on
8 nov. 2019 à 13:15

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it work by deleting lines by multiple of three?

Otherwise, you could do something like that:

For each line in your text file, check if the first characters are "Date", if this is true, delete the line.

(I can edit the answer to put some code if you still don't see what I'm suggesting)

EDIT:

Ok so it wasn't very clear that the "Date line" didn't start with the string "Date". But if you know the regular expression of the date (convert 8 nov. 2019 or 5 oct. 2018 in regex), you can then check each line for the regex and delete it accordingly.

Comment: It wouldn't work because some message are on lines of a multiple of 3

Comment: Ok I see. What about my suggestion of checking if the string "Date" is at the beginning of the line? Look at Maharshi Bingumalla answer, this is exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that but the line doesn't start with "date", it start with a number but some message also starts with a number so I can't delete every lines that start with a number.
I added an exemple of my text file in my question.

Comment: Yes I didn't get that sorry, I edited my question. You should definitely use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite_srt = ''

# Read the file with date
with open('x.txt', 'r') as f_read:
    for line in f_read:
        if not line.startswith('Date'):
             rewrite_srt += line


# Write the new file without date

with open('y.txt', 'w') as f_write:
     f_write.write(rewrite_srt)
```

Yield

```
Name (2 participants)

Message
```

Skipping each X lines:

```
rewrite_srt = ''
count = 0
skip_each = 5

# Read the file with date
with open('x.txt', 'r') as f_read:
    for line in f_read:
        count +=1
        if count == skip_each:
             count = 0
        else:
             rewrite_srt += line


# Write the new file without date

with open('y.txt', 'w') as f_write:
     f_write.write(rewrite_srt)
```

Yield

```
Name (2 participants)

Message
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but as I said, I can't look for "Date" because the line doesn't start with date, it start with a number but some message also starts with a number so I can't delete every lines that start with a number.

Comment: @Logrytoor I see. I added another piece of code if you are sure that the spacement between line.is always the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raphael, that was exactly what I was looking for, your code works perfectly ! Thanks again, have a great day

Comment: I did what you asked for: "How to delete a line every 3 lines". -:)

Comment: Yeah, I was really struggling to do this not so simple task ahah

Answer (score 0):

Since 'à' is common in that line, Do this:

```
   with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("filename.txt", "w") as f:
       for line in lines:
        if 'à' not in line:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but as I said, I can't look for "Date" because the line doesn't start with date, it start with a number but some message also starts with a number so I can't delete every lines that start with a number.

Comment: Thanks again but à is a very used words in french so every lines with à in messages will also be deleted. Don't worry, I got some goods answers here !

Answer (score 0):

If the file always has three lines per message, you want something like this:

```py
from itertools import groupby

all_messages = []
with open("messages.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(in_file):
        if line_num % 3 == 0: # First line of every three
            participant = line.strip()
        elif line_num % 3 == 1: # Second line of every three
            content = line.strip()
        elif line_num % 3 == 2: # Third line of every three
            all_messages.append((participant, content))

all_messages.sort(key=lambda message: message[0]) # Messages must be sorted for groupby
for participant, messages in groupby(all_messages, lambda message: message[0]):
    with open(f"{participant}.txt", "w") as out_file:
        for message in messages:
            out_file.write(f"{message[1]}\n") # Include newline
```